# Error while installing Oracle IDAM Suit "FROM_CD_LABEL matches with the value in file 'disk.label'"

Tags: oracle, installation

Recently we were facing following error while installing Oracle Identity and Access Management Suit. Error is "FROM_CD_LABEL matches with the value in file 'disk.label'" . It was when we were specifying the Disk2 Path for the installation.

We were installing the IDM suit on Oracle Linux VM (version-7.2) having Windows-10 machine as Host. We were extracting the .zip installation directory in windows and using the same for linux installation. Disk1 & Disk3 was not throwing any error however Disk2 was giving this exception.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this we just extracted Disk2 in Linux environment, and the issue gets resolved!!!